# Working with Captured data in OpenAL

Tags: c, capture, openal

I wanted to make a simple voice chat program and using OpenAL. On one side i capture voice and send it througth the internet(using Boost.Asio), so on the other side i just need to play that captured voice. BUT my problem is that i manage to capture voice say, 5 seconds but on the the other side(i mean another client, computer) plays that 5 second voice only very first second not the whole data. I don`t understand what is wrong with my code, please help me with it and any your suggestions are VERY important to me. 
Thank you in advance!!!

```
captureDev = alcCaptureOpenDevice(NULL, 8000, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, 800);
```

//...
//...

```
lastTime = currentTime;
    // Capture (roughly) five seconds of audio 

    ALubyte           captureBuffer[104857];
    ALubyte           *captureBufPtr;
        alcCaptureStart(captureDev);
        samplesCaptured = 0;
        captureBufPtr = captureBuffer;
        while (currentTime < (lastTime + 5))
        {
            // Get the number of samples available 
            alcGetIntegerv(captureDev, ALC_CAPTURE_SAMPLES, 1, &samplesAvailable);

            // Copy the samples to our capture buffer 
            if (samplesAvailable > 0)
            {
                alcCaptureSamples(captureDev, captureBufPtr, samplesAvailable);
                samplesCaptured += samplesAvailable;
                printf("Captured %d samples (adding %d)\r", samplesCaptured,
                    samplesAvailable);
                fflush(stdout);

                // Advance the buffer (two bytes per sample * number of samples) 
                captureBufPtr += samplesAvailable * 2;
            }

            // Wait for a bit 
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

            // Update the clock 
            currentTime = time(NULL);
        }
```

so i send the captured data **captureBuffer** with **samplesCaptured** and on another side(client) i receive them and want to play.

```
// Generate an OpenAL buffer for the captured data 
    alGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    alGenSources(1, &source);
    alBufferData(buffer, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, captureBuffer, samplesCaptured * 2, 8000);
    alSourcei(source, AL_BUFFER, buffer);
    alSourcePlay(source);

    // Wait for the source to stop playing 
    playState = AL_PLAYING;
    while (playState == AL_PLAYING)
    {
        printf("  source %d is playing...\r", source);
        fflush(stdout);
        alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &playState);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
```

As i said above it plays not the whole data.